# In git diff, how to combine --ignore-matching-lines with --name-only

Tags: git

I am using [`git diff --ignore-matching-lines='<regex>'`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-matching-linesltregexgt) to ignore changes. It
works as expected, files that contain only changes I want to ignore are not shown.

However, if I add the `--name-only` option, all modified files are listed, including files
that should have been ignored. `--ignore-matching-lines` seems to have no affect in combination
with `--name-only` or `--name-status`. Is there a workaround?

How to combine `git diff` options `--ignore-matching-lines` and `--name-only`?

Comment: You can't: `--name-status` uses a shortcut that doesn't actually run the diff algorithm, and as a result, all modifiers *to* the diff algorithm—including ignoring whitespace changes or ignored lines—never get run either. (This is a defect in Git—or arguably a "bug", but at least the documentation should note the limitation.)